# Old Task Definitions Becoming InActive on Creating New Definitions with serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, serverless, aws-fargate

I am Using Serverless to create task definitions and use this to work with step functions.

Here When I update my task definition in serverless and deploy it, prev task definitions become inactive and not able to use them further.

How to not make inactive prev Task-definitions?

Below is my serverless.yml

```yaml
service: my-service

useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'alpha'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'ap-south-1'}
  profile: ${opt:profile, 'default'}
  memorySize: 1280
  timeout: 600

plugins:
  - serverless-step-functions
package:
  individually: true
  patterns:
    - '!./**'

stepFunctions:
  stateMachines:
    ...
    ...

  validate: true # enable pre-deployment definition validation (disabled by default)

resources:
  Resources:
    fargateProjectCluster:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
      Properties:
        ClusterName: ${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}
    fargateTaskDefinition:
      Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
      Properties:
        ContainerDefinitions:
          - Name: new_definition
            Image: ...
            Privileged: false
            ReadonlyRootFilesystem: false
            Essential: true
            LogConfiguration:
              ...
              ...
        Cpu: ${env:CPU_UNITS}
        ExecutionRoleArn: !GetAtt ecsTaskExecutionRole.Arn
        Family: "${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}"
        Memory: ${env:MEMORY_UNITS}
        NetworkMode: "awsvpc"
        RuntimePlatform:
          OperatingSystemFamily: LINUX
          CpuArchitecture: X86_64
        RequiresCompatibilities:
          - FARGATE
        TaskRoleArn: !GetAtt fargateTaskRole.Arn
    fargateCloudWatchLogsGroup: ...
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What specific issue are you encountering? Do you still want to launch new ECS tasks with a previous ECS task definition for some reason?

Comment: Yes, @MarkB , I need to work with both versions at the same time, when we create it using AWS Console it's working fine, but when using serverless prev version moves into an inactive state.

Comment: What is the inactive state preventing you from doing exactly?